# pyspark write stream to delta no data

Tags: pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming, delta-lake

I use Pyspark to readStream from kafka, process and writeStream to delta table.

```
pyspark 3.2.1
io.delta 1.2.2
hadoop 3.3.0
```

This code does not produce any results to output delta when deployed in kubernetes or running in databricks.

am I producing no data?

When I run display without writeStream part in databricks then I see the data.

What's happening?

```
def run(spark, window_duration, watermark_delay):
    input_time_col = "timestamp"

    keep_original_cols = [input_time_col, "topic"]

    raw_message_data = StructType([
        StructField("col1", StringType(), True),
        StructField("col2", StringType(), True),
        StructField("col3", StringType(), True),
        StructField("col4", IntegerType(), True),
        StructField("col5", IntegerType(), True),
    ])

    return (spark
            .readStream
            .format("kafka")
            .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", KAFKA_SERVERS)
            .option("subscribe", INPUT_TOPIC)
            .option("startingOffsets", STARTING_OFFSETS)
            .option("maxOffsetsPerTrigger", MAX_OFFSETS_PER_TRIGGER)
            .option("failOnDataLoss", FAIL_ON_DATA_LOSS)
            .option("minPartitions", MIN_PARTITIONS)
            .load()
            .withColumn("tmp", from_json(col("value").cast("string"), raw_message_data))
            .select(f"tmp.*", *keep_original_cols)
            .withWatermark(input_time_col, watermark_delay)
            .groupBy(
                window(col(input_time_col), window_duration).alias("period"),
            )
            .agg(
                count("*").alias("query_count")
            )
            .withColumn("period_start", expr("period.start"))
            .withColumn("date", expr("date(period_start)"))
            .withColumn("hour", expr("hour(period_start)"))
            .withColumn("minute", expr("minute(period_start)"))
            .writeStream
            .outputMode(OUTPUT_MODE)
            # .partitionBy("date", "hour")
            .format(OUTPUT_FORMAT)
            .option("mergeSchema", "true")
            .option("checkpointLocation", CHECKPOINT_LOCATION))


query = run(spark, "2 minutes", "1 minuteS")
query.start(OUTPUT_PATH).awaitTermination()
```

I see _delta_log but no data appended.

EDIT:
constants:

```
KAFKA_SERVERS = "...my kafka servers..."
INPUT_TOPIC = "some-topic"
MAX_OFFSETS_PER_TRIGGER = "1000"
STARTING_OFFSETS = "latest"
FAIL_ON_DATA_LOSS = "false"
MIN_PARTITIONS = "288"

WINDOW_DURATION = "2 minutes"
WATERMARK_DELAY = "30 seconds"

OUTPUT_FORMAT = "delta"
OUTPUT_MODE = "append"
CHECKPOINT_LOCATION = "wasbs://...someCheckpointLocation"
OUTPUT_TABLE_PATH = "wasbs://....blob.core.windows.net/output"

PARTITIONING_COLS = ["col1", "col2"]
```

EDIT2:

running this part in databricks works fine:

```
    df = (
    spark
    .readStream
    .format("kafka")
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", KAFKA_SERVERS)
    .option("subscribe", INPUT_TOPIC)
    .option("startingOffsets", STARTING_OFFSETS)
    .option("maxOffsetsPerTrigger", MAX_OFFSETS_PER_TRIGGER)
    .option("failOnDataLoss", FAIL_ON_DATA_LOSS)
    .option("minPartitions", MIN_PARTITIONS)
    .load()
    .withColumn("tmp", from_json(col("value").cast("string"), raw_message_data))
    .select(f"tmp.*", *keep_original_cols)
    .withWatermark(input_time_col, watermark_delay)
    .groupBy(
        window(col(input_time_col), window_duration).alias("period"),
    )
    .agg(
        count("*").alias("query_count")
    )
    .withColumn("period_start", expr("period.start"))
    .withColumn("date", expr("date(period_start)"))
    .withColumn("hour", expr("hour(period_start)"))
    .withColumn("minute", expr("minute(period_start)"))
)
display(df)
```

Comment: what is the value of `OUTPUT_MODE` and other constants not shown here? How long did you wait?

Comment: @AlexOtt I have added constants.

Comment: if you wait less than 3 minutes (window duration + watermark) then data won't be populated...

Comment: @AlexOtt agreed hence I waited long enough ... please see EDIT2...running the code without writeStream shows me the data I want to write.

Comment: @AlexOtt is the problem caused by me using tumbling window in groupBy window function and no trigger as well?

Comment: wow, i have found that when i use "earlies" starting offset then it all works fine. why it does not work with latest when the topic has 1 million messages flowing into per second? it works fine with such implementation in spark+scala.

Comment: Hmmm... never saw such behavior

Comment: @AlexOtt I nailed it ... i set maxOffsetsPerTrigger to 1000 ... but i have 10^6 msgs per second flowing into the topic ... so i throttled unintentionaly the througput causing processing window to actually never close ... so it caused data to be all the time in memory and never spoiled to the output / appended to the output / window close was never triggered as i was processing data too slow ... i changed the value from 1k to 50M and it works fine. thanks anyway.

Comment: interesting case...

Comment: @DariuszKrynicki - can you please answer your own question, so other folks can easily see that this isn't an open question anymore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I throttled the througput by setting maxOffsetsPerTrigger for testing purposes as I limited number of executors to 3 while I have actually 10^6 messages incomming per second to the input topic.

This caused slow processing of incomming messages and window to never close so never appended the data.

Chaning `maxOffsetsPerTrigger` to 50,000,000 allowed me to process messages normally and the whole pipeline works.